# Type casting in haskell, Fractional and Int

Tags: haskell

I've written a function that (should) takes an infinite list of booleans and calculate the ratio of True to False values over the first n elements:

```
prob n list = foldr (+) 0 (map boolToInt (take n list)) / n
    where boolToInt b
        | b == True = 1
        | otherwise = 0
```

unfortunately that's not working:

```
No instance for (Fractional Int)
  arising from a use of `/'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Fractional Int)
In the expression: foldr (+) 0 (map boolToInt (take n list)) / n
In an equation for `prob':
    prob n list
      = foldr (+) 0 (map boolToInt (take n list)) / n
      where
          boolToInt b
            | b == True = 1
            | otherwise = 0
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I tried to make a conversion, but that isn't working either:

```
prob n list = foldr (+) 0 (map boolToInt (take (fromIntegral (toInteger n)) list)) / n
    where boolToInt b
        | b == True = 1
        | otherwise = 0
```

It's compiling, but as soon as I try to call the function I get an error:

```
*Main> prob 50 toCoin1
<interactive>:1:6:
Ambiguous type variable `a0' in the constraints:
  (Num a0) arising from the literal `50' at <interactive>:1:6-7
  (Integral a0) arising from a use of `prob' at <interactive>:1:1-4
  (Fractional a0) arising from a use of `prob' at <interactive>:1:1-4
Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
In the first argument of `prob', namely `50'
In the expression: prob 50 toCoin1
In an equation for `it': it = prob 50 toCoin1
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're converting at the wrong place. Try just sticking a `fromRational` around the entire `foldr` and `n`.

```
prob n list = fromIntegral count / fromIntegral n
    where count = foldr (+) 0 (map boolToInt (take n list))
          boolToInt b
            | b == True = 1
            | otherwise = 0
```

Oh, and your `boolToInt` function is identical to `fromEnum` specialized to `Bool`s.

```
prob n list = fromIntegral count / fromIntegral n
    where count = foldr (+) 0 (map fromEnum (take n list))
```

---

The fundamental problem with what you tried to do was you imposed conflicting requirements on the first argument to `prob`. Your use of `toInteger` constrained `n` to be `Integral`, but its use in `/` required that it be `Fractional`, and there's no type that's both `Integral` and `Fractional`.

Comment: That doesn't work for me, should `fromRational` be `fromIntegral`?

Comment: @dbaupp: Err, yeah it should. Guess I shouldn't be coding in a web browser.

Comment: @dbaupp: BTW if you write a top-level type declaration for `prob`, e.g. `prob :: Int -> [Bool] -> Float`, then you'll get a better error message.

Comment: Never write b==True.  Kittens die for such atrocities.

Comment: So true!  I see people do this in C code, and it makes my skin crawl (not to mention the fact that 1 is only one of many truthy values in C).

Comment: Please don't use foldr (+) 0 to do a sum, this will construct a huge thunk of the form `1+(0+(0+(1+...+0))..)` before making the sum (because (+) is strict in its second argument). Either use `foldl' (+) 0` or `sum` (and this second only with optimisation -O2 or it's too lazy).

Answer (score 0):

`Bool` is an instance of `Enum`, so `boolToInt` is already provided by `fromEnum`.  Also, the `foldr` is doing `sum`, so the whole function can be simplified to:

```
prob n list = (fromIntegral . sum . map fromEnum . take n) list / fromIntegral n
```

We could abstract out the code for computing the mean (although this will have to determine the length of the list, which we already know):

```
mean xs = (fromIntegral . sum) xs / (fromIntegral . length) xs

prob n = mean . map fromEnum . take n
```

Comment: The mean function is a bad consumer : it use xs in two spots so it will retain the head of xs until the sum has gone to the last element. The whole list will have to be in memory... The usual response to that is to accumulate both the sum and the length in one traversal : `foldl' (\(!sum, !len) x -> (sum+x,len+1)) (0,0)`.

Comment: It's pretty hard to detect this kind of case and to be sure of the right way to do this (there are lazyness concerns to consider too, you wouldn't want this to be done for all operators...). On the other hand, if you start writing parallel code, even the original mean parallelized can be a good consumer (since both traversals can happen simultaneously).